# Import error when running pytest with both a src and test directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am having a hard time understanding why my Flask app runs fine, and all imports work. But when I run pytest the same code can't resolve imports. Here is a sample app structure:

```
+-- mainFolder
|   +-- src
|       +-- app.py
|       +-- resources
|           +-- AppConfig.py
|   +-- test
|       +-- v1
|           +-- test_someTest.py
|   +-- conftest.py
```

Like I said, running app.py works. I can import `AppConfig` no problem. Everything works. However, when I run `python -m pytest` I get:

```
ImportError while loading conftest 'C:\...\conftest.py'.
conftest.py:2: in <module>
    from src.app import app as flask_app
src\app.py:3: in <module>
    from resources.AppConfig import AppConfig
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resources'
```

Here is `conftest.py`:

```
import pytest
from src.app import app as flask_app


@pytest.fixture
def app():
    yield flask_app


@pytest.fixture
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()
```

Here is the relevant code in `app.py`:

```
from resources.AppConfig import AppConfig

with app.app_context():
    current_app.appConfig = AppConfig.getAppConfig()
```

Doesn't work. I have moved `conftest.py` to both directories. I have exported both directories to `PYTHONPATH`.

The only way this works is when I move the `test` folder buck into the `src` directory... then there are no issues.

Does anyone have insight? I am using Python 3.8. I do not want to use virtual environments, or `setup.py` at this point. I had them configured already and they are overkill at this point. I just need something simple.

Comment: does your ressource folder has a` ```__init__.py``` ?
If not python shouldn't be able to know that there is a file name AppConfig.py in ressources and so he cant find it

Comment: It used to, but its Python 3.8. I thought __init__.py was redundant?